# Aggregate Milliseconds by hour

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I got a tbl with a timestamp (dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss) and duration in milliseconds

how can I aggregate these durations by, lets say hour? It should tell me the AVG milliseconds per hour.

SAMPLE:

```
Timestamp              Duration
10.10.2010 12:30:20    200
10.10.2010 12:59:10    400
```

OUTPUT:

```
Timestamp              Duration
10.10.2010 12:00:00    300
```

Comment: Do you mean duration present inside timestamp sting?? or a separate column?

Comment: duration is a seperate column

Comment: Can you spot samples of input and desired output?

Comment: added a sample to post

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("Date", 'HH24'), AVG("Duration") FROM "Table" GROUP BY TO_CHAR("Date", 'HH24')
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are looking for ROUND and AVG**

```
WITH DATASET
    AS (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 1:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               200 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 1:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               100 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 2:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               300 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 3:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               500 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 4:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               600 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '11/8/2013 4:16:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS TS,
               700 AS DURATION
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT ROUND ( TS, 'Hh24' ) AS TIMESTAMP_VAL,
       AVG ( DURATION ) AS DURATION
FROM
      DATASET
GROUP BY
      ROUND ( TS, 'Hh24' )
ORDER BY
      TIMESTAMP_VAL;
```

**NOTE:** extract(hour from systimestamp) will be subtracting the time zone offset

Comment: +1 Personally, I'd use `TRUNC` instead of `ROUND`, but the concept's the same.